# Custom tab bar in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs

Hello I am new to ionic and trying to achieve a custom tab bar as follows

**Expected Output**
[image]

**Current Output**
[image]

Bellow is my code so far

home.scss

```
ion-tabs {
  ion-tab-bar {
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    --color: var(--ion-color-white);
    --background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
  }
  ion-tab-button {
    ion-label {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 10px;
    }
    opacity: 0.75;

    ion-icon {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    ion-icon[ng-reflect-name='add-circle-outline'] {
      font-size: 40px;
    }
  }
  ion-tab-button.tab-selected {
    opacity: 1;
    ion-label {
      font-weight: 600;
    }
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button
      *ngFor="let item of navigationItems; index as i"
      [tab]="item?.route"
      (click)="item?.click ? item?.click() : null"
      id="tabButton-{{ i }}"
    >
      <ion-icon [name]="item?.icon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>{{item?.name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

home.ts

```
  navigationItems = [
    { name: 'Home', route: 'dashboard', icon: 'home' },
    { name: 'Calendar', route: 'calendar', icon: 'calendar' },
    { icon: 'add-circle-outline', click: () => this.openBottomSheet() },
    { name: 'Reports', route: 'reports', icon: 'stats-chart-outline' },
    { name: 'Settings', route: 'settings', icon: 'settings' },
  ];
```

Can someone please help me achieve as shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code as follows and it worked for me

**home.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button
      *ngFor="let item of navigationItems; index as i"
      [tab]="item?.route"
      (click)="item?.click ? item?.click() : null"
      id="tabButton-{{ i }}"
    >
      <ion-icon [src]="item?.src" [name]="item?.icon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label *ngIf="item.src == null">{{item?.name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

**home.ts**

```
navigationItems = [
    { name: 'Home', route: 'dashboard', icon: 'home' },
    { name: 'Calendar', route: 'calendar', icon: 'calendar' },
    { src: 'assets/images/tab-bar-add.svg', click: () => this.openBottomSheet() },
    { name: 'Reports', route: 'reports', icon: 'stats-chart-outline' },
    { name: 'Settings', route: 'settings', icon: 'settings' },
  ];
```

**home.scss**

```
ion-tabs {
  ion-tab-bar {
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    --color: var(--ion-color-white);
    --background: var(--ion-tab-bar-background);
  }
  ion-tab-button {
    ion-label {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 10px;
      color: var(--ion-color-white-light);
    }

    ion-icon {
      font-size: 24px;
      color: var(--ion-color-white-light);
    }

    ion-icon[ng-reflect-src='assets/images/tab-bar-add.svg'] {
      width: 80%;
      height: 80%;
    }
  }
  ion-tab-button.tab-selected {
    ion-label {
      font-weight: 600;
      color: var(--ion-color-tab-selected);
    }
    ion-icon {
      color: var(--ion-color-tab-selected);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `ion-fab-button` to show big button in center.
For Example:

```
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="newspaper"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>   

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="construct"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab4">
      <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>

  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button routerDirection="root" color="warning" >
      <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Check This Stackblitz for more info:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-gckq8n?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftabs%2Ftabs.page.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your button position is 2 so we will insert a custom class inside It programmatically.
home.html (changed code):

```
<ion-tab-button
      *ngFor="let item of navigationItems; index as i"
      [tab]="item?.route"
      (click)="item?.click ? item?.click() : null"
      id="tabButton-{{ i }}"
      [ngClass]="{'add-btn':i===2 ? true : false}"
    >
      <ion-icon [name]="item?.icon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>{{item?.name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
```

Then add Its style to scss file :

```
.add-btn {
  ion-icon {
    color: #fcad07;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 55px !important;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```